# Getting unknown value on Y axis while plotting barplot(Geom_Col)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a Col Graph B/W Diamonds$Clarity and Diamonds$price.
The code which I am using :

```
ggplot(data = diamonds, aes(clarity , price) ) +
  geom_col() +
  theme_dark(11, base_family = "")+ 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)
```

my output to this is

[image]

I have used Scale_y_continous to convert Y axis exponential value to Long values.
The data says the value of price, range from 326 to 18000 and I am getting value in my graph as millions on Y axis????

Comment: each level of `clarity` has many prices, do you intend to plot the mean (or max) price by `clarity`? It looks to me you are plotting the sum of prices per clarity.

Comment: See here diamonds %>% 
  group_by(clarity) %>% 
  skim(price)

and

diamonds %>% 
  group_by(clarity) %>%  
  dplyr::summarise(price.sum=sum(price))

geom_col sums your prices per clarity category

Comment: @zoowalk can you please be little discriptive

Comment: If you sum the prices per category (e.g. with the dplyr package) you will see that the sum of prices for each category is equivalent to the hight of the bars in your graph:

library(dpylr)
diamonds %>% 
  group_by(clarity) %>%  
  dplyr::summarise(price.sum=sum(price))

geom_col sums your prices per clarity category, so the chart is as expected.

As @missuse already wrote - do you want to have the mean price per category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct use plotly as it has better look and feel, also it has many options like zoom , save and etc.
regarding your point what you can do is use plotly and declare x in your plotly ase and y in your barplot ase with + or %>%.

it will work fine with you.